# How to get the urlHelper from html helper context in asp.net core mvc html helper static method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a project in `ASP.NET 5 RC1` which I used to get the the urlHelper from the HtmlHelper Context in my HTMLHelper static methods

```
    public static IHtmlContent MyHtmlHelperMethod<TModel, TResult>(
            this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {



       //get the context from the htmlhelper and use it to get the urlHelper as it isn't passed to the method from the view
        var urlHelper = GetContext(htmlHelper).RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelper>();

        var controller = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string myLink;
        if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"] == null)
        {
            myLink= urlHelper.Action("index", controller);

        } else
        {

            string area = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString();
            myLink = urlHelper.Action("index", controller, new { area = area });

        }  
        string output = "<div><a href = \"" + myLink + "\" class=\"myclass\"><blabla></blabla>My Link</a></div>;
        return new HtmlString(output.ToString());
    }
```

However in `ASP.NET Core` it no longer works and I get the runtime error

```
>InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper' has been registered.
```

The solution posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696337/unable-to-utilize-urlhelper) stackoverflow answer is to inject `IUrlHelperFactory`, however I am using static html helper methods I call in my `cshtml` and not classes which is used in taghelpers.

How do I change my code to work in `ASP.net Core` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your original code to:

```
var urlHelperFactory = GetContext(htmlHelper).RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
var actionContext = GetContext(htmlHelper).RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I got to say it is not beautiful and I would have like asp.net core developers to make this a little easier

Comment: I don't know if this is a new .net core 2.1 thing, but the above now yields an error for me saying IActionContextAccessor is not registered. See my answer below, which is now down to two lines of code. Yay.

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft may have moved things about a bit in .net core 2.1. It is slightly simpler than the accepted answer. I hope this is helpful to somebody.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyApp.Extensions
{
    public static class WebApiHelperExtension
    {
        public static IHtmlContent WebApiUrl(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
            var urlHelperFactory = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
            var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but where would you get htmlhelper instance?

Comment: It is passed in automatically via DependencyInjection, so you don't need to get it.
You can call the function from a .cshtml file without the parameter:
```@Html.WebApiUrl()```

Comment: Well, the html helper is the `Html` part in `@Html.WebApiUrl`, passed as a "this parameter". Not really dependency injection as such.